# Show the suffixIcon after the suffixText in a textField

Tags: flutter, text, icons, textfield, suffix

I just wanted to show the suffixIcon after the suffixText.
Now I know that in the InputDecoration documentation says explicitly that it will show the suffixText before the suffixIcon.

What would I like to do is:

[image]

the '*' represents that it's a mandatory field.

And I'm getting this :

[image]

is there a way for me to change the order of the suffixes in my TextField?

I tried using SizedBox, or Container widgets but never got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <del>`suffix`</del> (edit: `suffixIcon`) property and pass in a `Row` widget instead. Put both elements in the `Row`, and you can decide exactly how you want them to appear. For example:

[image: demo]

Soure code:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // <-- important
      children: const [
        Icon(Icons.visibility, color: Colors.grey),
        SizedBox(width: 4), // add a small gap
        Text('*'), // second element
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Now I have the problem that it only shows the `suffix` when the `TextField`is focused.
After looking for a solution to that problem I've found that using `SuffixIcon` would solve this issue, but It would bring me right back to my first problem of the Suffix's order, because `SuffixIcon` always comes before ´Suffix` or `SuffixText`.

Comment: @RobinOpinião Ah sorry, `suffix` only shows when it's focused. You can use the same idea with `suffixIcon` tho - please see my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, use Row() widget for suffixIcon

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffix: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.visibility,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 5),
            Text(
              '*',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your suffixIcon property to:

```
suffixIcon: Center(
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                              Text(
                                "*",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

The alignments here are important to maintain.